# jquery example in asp.net is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying out the following jquery/asp.net code sample in Visual Studio 2013.  Unlike the example below -- in my exercise I have placed the c# code in the code behind page and I placed the jquery code with the aspx markup.  The gridview displays the data, but when I click on the button the alert is not invoked.  When I try setting debugging on the jquery, the jquery code is not being entered.  I would be grateful if someone could point out what I am missing:

Code-Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  var myTestList = new List<MyTestClass1>
  {
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 1, Name = "Name1"},
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 5, Name = "Name5"},
     new MyTestClass1 {ID = 6, Name = "Name6"}
  };


    GridView1.DataSource = myTestList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public class MyTestClass1
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>


<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

//--I'm doing this in code behind




</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSelect" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdID" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Name
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="Get Data" />
```

JavaScript

```
var gridView1Control = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

$('#<%= btnGetData.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
    //To uncheck the header checkbox when there are no selected checkboxes in itemtemplate
    $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', gridView1Control).each(function(item, index) {

        var id = $(this).next('input:hidden[id$=hdID]').val();
        alert(id);
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: I have to ask, but I'm assuming you don't have any console errors? What if you do View Source and manually enter the buttons client id?

Comment: Try to change this $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked'  in this $('input:checkbox[id="CheckSelect"]:checked'... I can't test, but at first look it seems wrong selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the element `CheckSelect` inside the `asp:GridView` `GridView1` gets the ID GridView1_ChkSelect_{row_index} and `hdID` gets the id `GridView1_hdID_{row_index}`. Here you are using the selector `$=` which

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

What you need is **`*=`**

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

Change your code like this.

```
$('input:checkbox[id*=CheckSelect]:checked',
    gridView1Control).each(function (item, index) {

    var id = $(this).next('input:hidden[id*=hdID]').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: No, no console errors -- but hey -- Wonderful!  *= was the trick!